# Uniform Continuity of a Function

Tags: real-analysis

The question is as follows:

Fix any $a>0$ and any $m \in \Bbb N$. Prove that $f\colon \Bbb Q \cap [-m,m] \to \Bbb R$ given by $f(x)=a^x$ is uniformly continuous.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Are you familiar with the definition of uniform continuity and the distinction from regular continuity (I find that this definition can be really subtle for new students)?

Comment: Also what tools do you have at your disposal, for instance can we use the mean value theorem of derivatives, etc.?

Comment: Yes I was trying to use the definition of uniform continuity.I do not want to use the concept of derivative here.

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $\epsilon \gt 0$ we want to *find* a $\delta$ such that $\vert a^x - a^t \vert \lt \epsilon$ whenever $0 \leq \vert x - t \vert \lt \delta$ for all $x,t\in[-m,m]$.

Consider the following,

$$\vert a^x - a^t \vert  = \vert a^t \vert \vert a^{x-t}-1 \vert.$$

Because $a^x$ is continous and $[-m,m]$ is compact we know it has a maximum value which we will denote with $M$. Note that $M \gt 0$. We will break the problem into 2 cases  (I) When $a$ is larger than $1$ and (II) when $a$ is less than $1$.

Case (I):

The following hold,

- $a^t \leq M \quad \forall t \in [-m,m]$
- $a^{x-t} \leq a^{\vert x-t \vert} \leq a^\delta $
- There exists a $\delta'\gt 0$ such that $\vert a^\delta-1 \vert \lt \epsilon/M$, this follows from the continuity of the exponential function at $0$.

Therefore we have

$$\vert a^x - a^t \vert  = \vert a^t \vert \vert a^{x-t}-1 \vert \leq M \vert a^{\delta}-1 \vert \leq M \epsilon/M = \epsilon$$

Where we chose $\delta \lt \delta'$.

I leave Case (II) to the reader.

Comment: Hope this helps, I assumed regular continuity of $a^x$ to get it.

Comment: I believe it is true in general that a continuous function on a compact set is always uniformly continuous on that set.

Comment: Thank you very much Spencer